# How to plot a histogram in spss using the bootstrap sample data?

Tags: spss

How to plot a histogram or save the sample data generated by SPSS bootstrap? We want to visually show the distribution of the statistic being sampled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap procedure does not provide a way to get the individual values, however, you might be able to get something similar pedagogically  by using the simulation procedure and choosing the empirical or categorical distribution for the variables.

Comment: The reason to choose the bootstrap method is to show the client the sampling distribution. It helps to make it more interpretable. Analytical approach is totally a blackbox to clients who do not understand statistics. Unfortunately, SPSS has given bootstrap option but did not provide a way to save the data generated.

If we simulate it may not be similar to the once SPSS might have generated

Comment: I figured the need was something like that.  If you know a little Python, you could adapt the Bootstrap Tool (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app?lang=en#/file/341a7ede-6a08-4ea4-a31e-070279f9cae6) for this purpose.  It can bootstrap almost any statistical command, and you could save the datasets.  The zip file includes a syntax example as well as the Python code.

Comment: This is little cumbersome but it is the only way in spss I think.